# Wake esp8266 from deep sleep with PIR but disable while running code

Tags: esp8266, interrupt, sleep

I am using an ESP8266 to control a ring of neopixels. I want to use a PIR to trigger a brief light show. I'm using batteries and need them to last as long as possible.

I have it working by checking the PIR for motion.  If there is motion I run the light show. If no motion I put the ESP8266 into deep sleep for 15 seconds. When I wake I try again.

I would prefer to use the PIR to reset the ESP, and I did get it to do that but the problem was that further movement would reset again and start the light show from the beginning. I would like to be able to disable reset while I'm running code.

I did some research and found this:

[PIR motion wake ESP8266 from deepsleep](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54625/pir-motion-wake-esp8266-from-deepsleep/54642#54642?newreg=39eea8186cf24833bc4f89d459642c41)

It's pretty much what I need.

Is there a final circuit diagram or a similar solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have being using the circuit below now for a few weeks and all seems to work.

When I wake from deep sleep I set the Latch pin to 0 to prevent any more resets. I do the work, I check if there is still motion by reading PIR out, if no movement I set the Latch pin to 1 and go into deep sleep.
[image: Circuit diagram to prevent repeated resets when waking from deep sleep]

Comment: Have you measured the current consumption when the PIR is not detecting anything ? To me it looks like 2.5mA if R3 is only 1k.

Comment: Updated R3 to 47K and works fine for the last few days. Thanks.